# Confused about activities and classes

Tags: android, class, android-activity

I'm implementing a list which needs to be displayed by an activity and modified (add items, remove items, sort) by the user. Currently I have two different classes - the activity class and the list class which has all the operations on the list. However, the activity class is going to need access to the list in order to adapt and display it, and it seems kind of clumsy to either duplicate the list for the activity or make the list public. I get the feeling I might not be understanding what activities are correctly - should my two classes really be one single class? I assumed activities were mostly for UI, not for modifying the underlying datastructure.

Comment: I dont think anyone can answer without an example of your code or what you are trying to do :)

Comment: @davidkonrad Check my answer. See if it needs improvements. :)

Comment: +1 for improving your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*`I'm implementing a list which needs to be displayed by an activity and modified (add items, remove items, sort) by the user.`*

You can do the simple operations defined by the `List<T>` interface like add, remove, etc. You can write a custom `Comparator<T>` to perform sort operations. Then use the  `Collections.sort()` method to do your work.

---

*`Currently I have two different classes - the activity class and the list class which has all the operations on the list.`*

It depends. I generally prefer to make a singleton instance of the list and let my activity modify it on callbacks from `ListView`. There is nothing clumsy about letting your Activity handle the addition or removal from list.

---

*`However, the activity class is going to need access to the list in order to adapt and display it, and it seems kind of clumsy to either duplicate the list for the activity or make the list public.`*

Like I said, look up what a **Singleton Instance** is. Share your list across multiple activities by creating a class that has the list in it. Declare the list public.  That way, you share the list and do not duplicate it. Remember: if you duplicate the data multiple times. keeping them in sync is going to be a tough nut to crack.

Answer (score 3):

Activities are the main building blocks of Android, all the different screens that you see in your  Application are [Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html). You should understand that not all `Java Classes` used in your Android App are Activities (only those Java Classes that `extends Activity` are Activities).

The Java Classes that are not Activity (used in your code) can be simply plain `Data Models`, `Custom Adapters`, `Custom Views`, `Database Handlers`, `Services`, and so on.

All these Java files are used separately from the Activity Class to provide Modularity and to avoid creating a Mess and deficiency by implementing all the Functionality in a Single Activity Class.

You use the instances of these other Java Classes (or use them statically) in your Activity Class.

For Displaying a Simple List, you can use `ListView` widget, and you don't really need a separate class for it's implementation. Likewise, if you are preparing to implement a ListView with functionality such as Delete, Add, Update, etc. Then Custom ListView is the alternative option that you can use.

You cannot implement a Custom List View in a single Activity Class, you will be needing a `Custom Adapter Class`, a `Custom Data Model Class` and other related classes for it's implementation.

Here is a list of some useful tutorials for implementing Simple and Custom ListViews:

1. [Vogella's ListView Tut](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)
2. [The Open Tutorials](http://theopentutorials.com/tag/android-custom-listview-example/)
3. [Android Example 1](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129)
4. [Android Example 2](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Think about it like that. Your oncreate is called once. If you need things done on the list, they will most probably be on your onItemClick, onItemLongClick kinda events. And when that happens, you should call a AsyncTask, coded in your same activity, so that the onPostExecute can modify its UI elements and the list. Some example below.

**Note, the code below has been reduced bigtime, so excuse syntax**

```
package com.taxeetaregistration;


public class Bookings extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener {

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private LinkedList<BookingRecord> bookingRecord;
    private ListView customerList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bookings);
        Log.d("Taxeeta", "Entered BookingExperience");

        bookingRecord = new LinkedList<BookingRecord>();

        customerList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        customerList.setAdapter(new CustomerList());
        customerList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        getBookings = new GetBookings();
        getBookings.execute();
    }

    public class CustomerList extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bookingresponse_row, null);
                final CustomerViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomerViewHolder();
                viewHolder.customerRow = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customerRow);
                viewHolder.customerName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customerName);
                viewHolder.customerPhoneNumber = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.customerPhoneNumber);

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            // Setting all values in listview
            String temp = bookingRecord.get(position).customer.getFullName();
            ((CustomerViewHolder) (convertView.getTag())).customerName.setText(temp);

            temp = bookingRecord.get(position).customer.getPhoneNumber();
            ((CustomerViewHolder) (convertView.getTag())).customerPhoneNumber.setText(temp);

            return convertView;
        }

    public class GetBookings extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Object> {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            connectToServer();

                    //Do all network related work here, and update
        publishProgress(j);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (bookingRecord != null && bookingRecord.size() > 0) {
                busy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ((BaseAdapter) customerList.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

            } else {
                progressBarUpper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Log.d("Taxeeta", "No cabbies found");
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... i) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(i);
            boolean found = false;
            customersFound.setText("" + totalCabbiesSubscribed);
            BookingRecord newRecord = new BookingRecord();
        newRecord.customerJourney = customerJourney;
        newRecord.customer = customer;

        bookingRecord.addLast(newRecord);
            customersConfirmed.setText("" + bookingRecord.size());
        }
    }

    private class CustomerViewHolder {
        public LinearLayout customerRow;
        public TextView customerName;
        public TextView customerPhoneNumber;
        public TextView customerFrom, customerTo;
        public ListView cabbieList;
        public float distanceFromCustomer = -1.0f;
    }

    public class BookingRecord {
        public BookingRecord() {
            cabbies = new ArrayList<CabbieDetails>();
        }

        public IJourneyDetails customerJourney;
        public IUserDetails customer;
        public SearchResultsConcrete cabbieList;
        public ArrayList<CabbieDetails> cabbies;
    }

}
```